# How to reduce phase noise in radar?

Tags: noise, phase, radar

Instability of oscillator can introduce phase noise to the signal received by radar [1].

Are there commonly used digital signal processing methods can reduce the phase noise?

[1] Aubry, Augusto, et al. "Radar phase noise modeling and effects-part I: MTI filters." IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic Systems 52.2 (2016): 698-711.

Comment: Try using PLL ?

Comment: If you're worried about phase noise for range estimation, you can use multi-pulse integration. I think either coherent or non-coherent integration would help although usually coherent integration is better if you want improved SNR.